# Address Verification Failed / View on Tresor Address don't Match

Tags: address, verification, trezor

Using LTC wallet on new Trezor. On "Receive Payment" tab, clicking eyeball icon, the address shown on the Trezor does not match the address shown on screen.

What gives? Did I already get hacked?

Answer (score 0):

Addresses on LTC transitioned to a new format right about this time.  You are probably looking at the same address on both the website and the LCD, but they are just in different formats.